# Silverlight 5 and x64 Sidebar

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I am developing a sidebar gadget for windows 7 using Silverlight in an enterprise company (70K+ employees).

All of our windows 7 client builds are x64, hence all the sidebar processes are running as x64.

Even though I know that there is an option switching to a 32 bit version,

I cannot allow this to myself – people will have to execute registry files, or a GPO will have to be applied, etc…

I have been desperately waiting for Silverlight 5th version since it’s supposed to have a 64 bit runtime.

Now, when sidebar starts the gadget, it says that I am missing Silverlight 5 runtime, suggesting to download it from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/coming-soon_5.0.0.html

There is a link on this page that leads me back to:

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-5-beta/

Where I have already downloaded the beta tools and runtime for Silverlight 5!

So what’s the problem? What am I missing here? Is there a x64 bit support or no ?

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

By the way – if I switch to a 32 bit sidebar version on PC – all works fine…

Comment: at page 17: http://i1.silverlight.net/content/downloads/silverlight_5_beta_features.pdf?cdn_id=1, 64bit support is listed in Silverlight 5 Features not included in this Beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Silverlight 5 RC version just released, with 64 bit support
http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/01/silverlight-5-rc-now-available